# Kotlin: Unusual behavior when dealing with sets

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple data class which stores x and y coordinates of a position. My use case is that a single object of this class will be created and updated, and I need to maintain a set of unique coordinates.

I've simplified my use case in the following code where adding the `pos` object directly to the set vs passing the copy of the object result in different behavior (please see the comment in the code).

My initial hunch was that it could be because Java/Kotlin is passing the object by reference and the `Set.add` compares on reference. However, that doesn't seem to be true, if I set the `pos.x` or `pos.y` to any other value then the `set.contains` method returns false.

Question:
If the comparison is by reference then why does it fail when setting to a value other than what is given in the below code? If comparison is by hash code then why does the `setByCopy` not return true in the original case?

```kotlin
data class Pos(var x: Int = 0, var y: Int = 0)

fun main() {
    val pos = Pos(0, 0)
    val set = mutableSetOf<Pos>()
    val setByCopy = mutableSetOf<Pos>()

    pos.x = -9
    pos.y = -6
    set.add(pos)
    setByCopy.add(pos.copy())

    println(pos.hashCode())


    pos.x = -8
    pos.y = -37
    // setting pos.y to any other value (e.g -35) will cause set.contains(pos) to return false.

    println(set.contains(pos))       // true, but expected false.
    println(setByCopy.contains(pos)) // false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that modifying the same instance via reference will affect all references. What was confusing to me is that `set.contains` method did not return true if a different value was assigned. Leading me to believe that it must be comparison by hash codes, which also wasn't true. @Louis' answer clarified it for me, I was not aware of the undefined behavior.

Comment: Even if we are talking about undefined behavior, your example seems consistent with what I'd expect. You are mutating the element in the set. When you call `contains` the set compares `pos` with `pos`, why would it return false?

Comment: When I do `set.contains(pos)` as per the example shared above it returns true. Fine, this may be because they are the same reference, now if I update `pos.y` to let's say -35 instead of -37 `set.contains(pos)` returns false. This should not be the case unless it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. Then probably the different behavior is due to the fact that two hashcodes (the one at the time of insertion and the one for -8, -37) fall into the same bucket for a set of that size.

Comment: @gpunto, yeah, but that also doesn't seem consistent. Although hashCode for the example shared above is the same but if that is the basis of comparison then `setByCopy.contains(pos)` should have returned true, but it did not. So the only reasoning is -- undefined behavior, as Louis mentioned.

Comment: `setByCopy.contains(pos)` returns false because first it uses the hashcode and then compares by equality. Both are used in the underlying implementation. When the hashcode resolves into an empty bucket it returns false eagerly, but if the bucket has objects, then it must compare by equality because of collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, modifying an element that's already in a set produces undefined behavior.  This is not explicitly documented in Kotlin, but carries over from Java, where it's documented:

> Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

This means that anything can happen: it can work or not work randomly.

Comment: Mmm. The same applies to map keys, too: you shouldn't make any change which affects the behaviour of their `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods, or Bad Things™ can happen. It's safest to use immutable objects as set items or map keys; if you must use mutable objects, then ensure they never get changed after being added to a container.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two objects, `pos` and then a *separate* one we'll call `pos2`. When you invoke `copy()` on an instance of a data class, you get a completely separate instance with its properties initialised to the same data.

Then you add each instance to a separate `Set`. Even though `set` contains `pos` and `setByCopy` contains `pos2`, if you call `setByCopy.contains(pos)` then that will return *true* because of how equality works for sets and data classes:

> [`boolean contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object))
>
> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that **`(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`**.

That `o.equals(e)` bit is important - a data class automatically generates an `equals()` implementation based on its data, i.e. the properties in the constructor. So `Pos(0, 0) == Pos(0, 0)` is *true* even though they're different instances, because they contain the same *data*.

This is why `setByCopy.contains(pos)` is true - not because it contains *that object*, but because it contains an object *that is equal to it*.

---

When you update `pos` with different numbers, now `pos` and `pos2` have different values for their data properties - they're no longer *equal*, so `setByCopy.contains(pos)` returns *false*.

`set.contains(pos)` still evaulates to *true* because *that set contains the `pos` object*. When you updated that object, the reference in the set is pointing to that same object, so of course it's equal to itself! If you wanted to create a distinct, separate instance that *doesn't* change when you update `pos`, then that's what `copy()` is for

Comment: When I update the `pos` object with a different value (other than what I've pasted above) `set.contains(pos)` does NOT evaluate to true. Hence, the source of my confusion as it's not what I would expect since the reference is still the same.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci oh I see your comment now, you didn't have an example of the unexpected behaviour earlier. Looks like it's doing the comparison based on hashcodes (which I'm guessing you've realised because of the numbers you've picked, where the "working" update results in one less *31* but adds it to the other value) - probably because `LinkedHashSet` (which is what Kotlin uses) is based on a hash table, so at insertion time it's based on that hashcode - so yeah, undefined behaviour if you mutate it!

Comment: Also for what it's worth, the default `hashCode` implementation for a data class only guarantees a match if the properties are all equal - it doesn't do anything clever to avoid false positives like you're getting when the ints just happen to align the same way. Also its `equals` implementation checks each property for equality, it's not relying on the hashcode, so that's more evidence that the set isn't actually using `equals` on the "live" objects: https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#data-class-declaration